# Laptop with tapered keys (i.e. not chiclets) OTHER than gaming laptop

Tags: laptop

It seems that, in the pursuit of thinness, major manufacturers have stopped making laptops with quality keyboards and now they all give you a chiclet keyboard except on high end gaming laptops. That's unfortunate, because I plan to use my laptop to type a lot, not to touch the screen, and I'll need to carry it on my back for miles.

Please prove me wrong and tell me there's a laptop with a 6th generation Core i5/7 in it AND a quality keyboard AND which isn't a bulky gaming laptop.

Comment: A reasonable question, but a little ranty. You might want to reword it some.

Comment: It might not be exactly what you need, but can you check out some of the new ThinkPads? I run several *30 series (quite old, but with the new style keyboard). Earlier today I was feeling so grateful for having a laptop with such an amazing keyboard, considering that mechanical keyboards have spoiled me significantly. I can't be bothered to write on a rubber dome keyboard anymore, but the scissors mechanism on ThinkPads makes it such a pleasure.

Comment: So far, Thinkpad keyboards are only second to Macbooks with respect to satisfying tactile feedback of current chiclet laptops I've tried.